# Using conditional typescript props with useContext

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Alright so on the application I am working on, I have a component called `InputElement`, where different HTML inputs (input, textarea, select, etc) can all use this component and share the same styles and properties (I use them with react-hook-form).

```js
type Variant =
  | {
      variant: 'select'
      list: string[]
    }
  | {
      variant: 'input'
      list?: never
    }
  | {
      variant: 'textarea'
      list?: never
    }
```

These are the variant props. Input and textarea are the same, but when we give `InputElement` a prop of `select`, it needs to have a `list` of strings to render just like the html `select` tag would have `option` tags inside of it (will transform to `option` later). So far, this works well.

```js
type Props = Variant & {
  /** Header of the InputElement */
  label: string

  /** Custom label to give the InputElement for form hook */
  registerLabel: string

  /** Input type of the field */
  type?: HTMLInputTypeAttribute
}
```

And these are the regular props. Pretty self explanatory there.

So I have tested this, and it works, but I'm trying to use it with `React.useContext` hook so I don't have to prop-drill all of these props.

createContext:

```js
const InputContext = createContext<Props>({
  label: 'Default Label',
  registerLabel: 'example',
  type: 'text',
  variant: 'input'
})
```

InputElement component:

```js
const InputElement = ({ label, registerLabel, type, ...props }: Props) => {
  const { register } = useFormContext()
  const { list, variant } = { ...props }
  return (
    <InputContext.Provider value={{ label, registerLabel, type, variant, list}}>
      <div className={styles.container} {...props}>
        <label>{label}</label>
        {getVariant(variant)}
      </div>
    </InputContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

(`getVariant` just returns the variant (input, textarea, select) that the component was passed).
But typescript throws an error over the react context initial `value` key with this long log that ends with `Type '"select"' is not assignable to type '"textarea"'` ???

I have never used conditional types before, and I love how I can apply it here, but this is killing me.
Any thoughts? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also wanted to add that I'm using Next.js, but should be irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you don't want/need the `list?: never`. Try your union with the list missing for variants that dont need it, then have a function which returns the right context shape for a given variant:

```
import { createContext, HTMLInputTypeAttribute } from "react";

type Variant =
  | {
      variant: "select";
      list: string[];
    }
  | {
      variant: "input";
    }
  | {
      variant: "textarea";
    };

type Props = Variant & {
  /** Header of the InputElement */
  label: string;

  /** Custom label to give the InputElement for form hook */
  registerLabel: string;

  /** Input type of the field */
  type?: HTMLInputTypeAttribute;
};

const InputContext = createContext<Props>({
  label: "Default Label",
  registerLabel: "example",
  type: "text",
  variant: "input"
});

const getInputContext = (props: Props): Props => {
  switch (props.variant) {
    case "select":
      return { ...props, variant: "select", list: props.list };
    default:
      return { ...props, variant: props.variant };
  }
};

const InputElement = (props: Props) => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  const { label, registerLabel, type, ...otherProps } = props;
  return (
    <InputContext.Provider value={getInputContext(props)}>
      <div className={styles.container} {...props}>
        <label>{label}</label>
        {getVariant(variant)}
      </div>
    </InputContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I'll stress what you are trying to achieve is a little odd. Condensing down JSX into configurable properties that just say what JSX to render, is potentially an anti pattern. What you would normally do is pass down the component into the core one, if you want some commonality. I think the abstraction you are introducing is potentially unnecessary indirection and is encouraging branching over composition (which is preferred).

Comment: Alright thanks for the quick reply! Your solution is all handy except for the `list` prop. So I switched the input and textarea declarations, and made input optional (I wanted it to be the default), and removed the `list?: never`s. Then moving into the object for values, I still have the error `Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'`, and I can't do any null checks or not null assertions

Comment: That sounds like what i'd expect. You *need* to type narrow here by checking if its undefined. Thats the right and proper thing to do here -- why cant we null check it? You need to, because it could indeed be undefined, and your code is only safe by checking it.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I'm not as strong syntactically in js, my knee-jerk reaction was to do something like this: `value={{ label, registerLabel, type, variant, (list && list) }}` but that just isn't correct. What am I missing?

Comment: Cool I think I understand a bit better now. Give me some mins to edit my answer with improvements.

Comment: Hey look at you! Thanks a million!